# Display Problem in C++ If Even Numbers is Inputted

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have a very simple problem when displaying the single "A". It should start on the **RIGHT SIDE** and not on the left. It is correct when i input **odd numbers** but if i input **even numbers** it outputs wrong.
I have to follow this guidelines by the way,

Guidelines:

1. Pointers and references must be used to display the values.
2. displayRoad runs recursively.
3. Loop statements are not allowed
4. Object instance must be destroyed after use.

Pls see the pictures below:

> WRONG RESULT (EVEN NUMBERS)

[image: WRONG RESULT]

> CORRECT RESULT (ODD NUMBERS)

[image]

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class myRoad
{
private:
 char myChar;
 int myH, myW;

public:
myRoad(){
  askChar();
  askHeight();
  askWidth();
}
void askChar();
void askHeight();
void askWidth();
void recurs_W(char c, int w, int h);
void recurs_H(char c, int h, int w);
char getChar(){return myChar;}
int  getHeight(){return myH;}
int  getWidth(){return myW;}
};

void displayRoad(myRoad* mRoad);

int main()
{
  myRoad* mRoad = new myRoad();

  cout << endl << endl;

  displayRoad(mRoad);

  delete mRoad;
}

void displayRoad(myRoad* mRoad)
{
    mRoad->recurs_H(mRoad->getChar(),mRoad->getHeight() * 2 + 1, mRoad->getWidth());
}


void myRoad::askChar()
{
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter a character: ";
    cin >> ch;
    myChar = ch;
}

void myRoad::askHeight()
{
    int h = 0;
    cout << "Enter height: ";
    cin >> h;
    myH = h;
}

void myRoad::askWidth()
{
    int w = 0;
    cout << "Enter width: ";
    cin >> w;
    myW = w;
}

void myRoad::recurs_H(char c, int h, int w)
{
    if(h == 0)
      return;
    recurs_W(c, w, h);
    recurs_H(c, --h,w);
}

void myRoad::recurs_W(char c, int w, int h)
{
   if(w == 0)
   {
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
   else
   {
     if(h % 2 == 1)
     cout << myChar;
     else
     {
        if (w == myW && h % 4 == 0)
        {
            cout << myChar;
        }
        else if (w == 1  && h % 2 == 0 && h % 4 != 0)
        {
            cout << myChar;
        }
        else
        cout << ' ';
     }
   }
    return recurs_W(c, --w, h);
}
```

Comment: By the way, using recursion for this is going to blow up your call stack quite quickly.... not really the best solution when iteration will do.

Comment: Off-topic: If you prefer local storage duration (`myRoad mRoad;`), you don't have to care for deletion (but good that you thought of!). If you should discover that your object is too large for the stack (which shouldn't be the case here), you can get same comfort by use of a smart pointer: `auto mRoad = std::make_unique<myRoad>();`

Comment: Strongly agreeing with Lightness – apart from, in your recursion, you decide by *remaining* height, not current height, if you want to draw the A on left or right. That reverses your structure in vertical direction. As for odd numbers the structure is axially symmetric, you won't notice, though.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica. Its ok. I just wanted to fix the error. Can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: @Aconcagua. Its ok. I just wanted to fix the error. Can you help me with that? Thank you

Comment: Well, best option you have is turning the algorithm into an iterative one. *If* you insist on recursive algorithm, you could provide an additional parameter "depth", counting up from 0 to height, and instead you'd leave height unchanged. You'll then be testing on depth instead of height, of course (depth for recursion depths – admitted, doesn't go well together with "height", please find a better name yourself...).

Comment: @Aconcagua. Could you edit my code to what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You choose whether to put the character on the right or left, depending on whether `h` is odd or even.

So, it is not surprising that making `h` start as an odd number (rather than an even one) should reverse that choice for the first step.

---

I propose you introduce a new variable `i`, that instead of going 10→0 (or 5→0), goes 0→10 (or 0→5).

<sup>(*I'm ignoring one-based indexing and exclusive ranges in the above numerical examples, but you get the point)*</sup>

Then make your left-or-right decision based on `i` instead of `h`, as it'll always start as even (0).

This variable would begin at zero and be incremented every time `h` is *decremented*, so it's the exact mirror.

---

You don't actually need to store `i` anywhere; you can just calculate it when needed:

```
int myRoad::currentRowNumber(int h)
{
   return getHeight() - h;
}
```

Then instead of, say, `h % 2`, you do `currentRowNumber(h) % 2`.

There are simpler ways to achieve the wider goal, but this is a quick fix that demonstrates the cause of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, no: I will let you remember how to write a member function. You already have eight of them in your program, so you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is converting your algorithm into an iterative one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myH; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < myW; ++j)
        std::cout << 'A';
    std::cout << '\n';

    if((i & 1) == 0)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < myW; ++j)
            std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "A\n";
}

if(myH != 0) // drop, if you want to have a single line for height = 0
{
    // final line:
    for(int i = 0; i < myW; ++i)
        std::cout << 'A';

    std::cout << std::endl; // in contrast to simple '\n', std::endl flushes the output
                            // stream as well, assuring user sees output immediately
}
```

*If* you insist on a recursive variant (be aware that you might suffer from stack overflow pretty quickly for larger widths and heights!): The problem is that you decide by *remaining* height, not current height, if you want to draw the A on left or right. That reverses your structure in vertical direction. As for odd numbers the structure is axially symmetric, you won't notice, though, but with even numbers, you get bitten.

You could fix that, for instance by providing an additional parameter indicating current height, which iterates from 0 to maximum height:

```
void myRoad::recurs_H(char c, int h, int w)
{
    if(h < myH)
    {
        recurs_W(c, w, h);
        recurs_H(c, ++h, w);
        //          ^^ (!)
    }
}
```

with initial call as:

```
recurs_H('A', 0, myW);
//            ^ (!)
```

I personally recommend re-organising the functions, though:

```
void myRoad::recurs_W(char c, int w)
{
    if(w < myW)
    {
        std::cout << c;
        recurse_W(c, w + 1);
    }
}

void myRoad::recurs_H(char c, int h)
{
    if(h < myH)
    {
        recurse_W(c, 0);
        std::cout << '\n';
        if((h & 1) == 0)
            recurs_W(' ', 1);
        std::cout << c << '\n';

        recurs_H(c, h + 1);
    }
}

void displayRoad(myRoad* mRoad)
{
    if(mRoad->getWidth() && mRoad->getHeight())
    {
        mRoad->recurs_H(mRoad->getChar(), 0);
        // draw the final line
        mRoad->recurs_W(mRoad->getChar(), 0);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See how much this resembles the iterative variant? See how far less complicated the `recurse_W` function got? Additionally, as you don't need the value of the member variable any more after the recursive call (the recursive call is the very last thing you do!), you can profit from tail call optimisation, which will prevent your stack from growing...

Negative width or height is pretty meaningless, isn't it? So you might consider changing the type to unsigned (and the recursive function parameters as well). Careful, though, when downcounting – people tend to overlook that unsigned numbers cannot get negative:

```
for(unsigned int n = 7; n >= 0; --n)
```

results in endless loop. But that's actually easily covered:

```
for(unsigned n = 8; n-- > 0; )
```

or, if you consider that unsigned overflows:

```
for(unsigned n = 7; n <= 7; --n)
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry i cannot use a loop. I have put it in my question

Comment: @Joseph Hm, so they want to teach you recursion? Otherwise, that requirement doesn't make sense at all... Actually, your display road is not recursive either, it just calls other recursive functions. Would that still satisfy the task?

Comment: Yes. That is ok

Comment: Actually, as the recurse-functions are member functions as well, you wouldn't need to pass maxH, you could always access myH directly instead!

Comment: I'm sorry where should i put this recurs_H('A', 0, myW)?;

Comment: Well, guess, where have you called the recurse_H function the very first time???

Comment: Would you rewrite my code.  It has errors  member function 'void myRoad::recurs_W(char, int)':
70:27: error: 'recurse_W' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Joseph You know, SO is not a code writing service at very first place. Additionally, if I *did* modify the code in your question, I'd invalidate all the comments and answers given so far. I changed the signatures in the definitions of the functions. Of course you'll have to adjust the declarations inside the class, too...